# Unable to post photo to Facebook using the graph api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My requirement is to post a photo to the Facebook using the Javascript SDK.
I am facing the following issues:

Firstly,

```
     FB.login(function (response) {                               
         if (response.authResponse) {
             var access_token = response.session.access_token;
             alert(access_token);
         } else {
             alert('User is logged out
        }
     }, true);
```

Every time i try to execute this piece of code I get authResponse:null, status:"unknown".

Secondly. I have registered my app with Facebook and can generate access token manually whenever I need one. Using the same access token, when I try to post a photo as follows:

```
                        var imgURL="http://www.photographyblogger.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/flower29.jpg";
                        FB.api('/photos', 'post', {
                            message: 'photo description',
                            access_token: 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN',
                            url: imgURL
                        }, function (response) {

                            if (!response || response.error) {
                                alert('Error occured:' + response.error.message);
                            } else {
                                alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
                            }

                        });
```

I get an alert "Post ID: 'SOME_VALUE'". But the photo doesn't get posted at all on my wall. Please help guys as it is an urgent work that I need to finish ASAP. Thanks!

Comment: For the second question, it sounds like maybe the post got posted to your albums, but not your wall. You may need to do another request to make it show up on the wall.

Comment: Hey Ben, even I thought so, but to my surprise the photo wasn't posted any where :( any clue what mistake am I making with the code?

Answer (score 2):

```
            var wallPost = {
                url: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
            };

            FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', wallPost , function(response) {
              if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occured');
              } else {
                alert('Post ID: ' + response);
              }
            });
```

This will post an image to your wall!

Comment: Hi Surya, Thanks for the answer, but my code worked the same day when i posted this question, it was just that i was trying to find the uploaded photos at the wrong place :) The api allows you to add photos but it doesn't publish them to your wall unless you permit. I was searching for the photos on my wall without permitting FB to publish them.

Comment: @TushiraGupta Hey, thats nice. I am even having a similar trouble. As I think you figured it out, can you answer this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123099/facebook-javascript-fb-ui-event-to-post-photo-on-friends-wall)

Comment: @TushiraGupta  how to permit them to publish on wall ?

Answer (score 1):

For posting photos to wall, you can do:

```
var imgURL="http://www.photographyblogger.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/flower29.jpg";

var wallPost = {
    message : "photo description",
    picture: imgURL
};
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', wallPost , function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response);
  }
});
```

Ref: [FB.api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, but I don't want to post it as an icon, it should be a posted like a proper photo.

Comment: post it to
`FB.api('/me/photos', 'post')`

Comment: @Tushira :you want to post to wall or album...?

Comment: I need to post the photo to the wall, but it should open like any other Facebook photo if I click on it. I have used "FB.api('/me/photos', 'post')" as well, the issue I am facing is : I get an alert "Post ID: 'SOME_VALUE'". But the photo doesn't get posted at all on my wall.

Comment: Also, to add an image like an icon I have already tried and tested the following code which works very well:                    <script>
shareurl="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=http://www.photographyblogger.net/&p[images][0]=http://www.photographyblogger.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/flower29.jpg";
</script>
<a onclick="window.open(shareurl, 'sharepopup', 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=no');">Share</a>                  But as I wrote, I dont want an icon, i need a proper photo.

Comment: can you give url of your app?

Comment: It is currently hosted on a local server.

Comment: Guys, my doubt is, if on posting it shows me the alert with Post Id: "SOME_NUMBER" that means the photo has been successfully posted. But when I see my wall, I don't find any post there. Am I making any mistake with my code?

Comment: @Sudhir: I used the code suggested by you                           var imgURL="http://www.photographyblogger.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/flower29.jpg";
var wallPost = {
    message : "photo description",
    access_token: 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN',
    picture: imgURL
};

FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', wallPost, function (response) {
if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured:' + response.error.message);
} else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
}

});
With this code I get the following error :(
({error:{message:"(#324) Requires upload file", type:"OAuthException", code:324}})

Comment: This code just requires some minor adjustments so that the Gupta gets what he wants!!