# Facebook Javascript fb.ui event to post photo on friends wall?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to create a button, when clicked, should open a Facebook dialog requesting user to post a photo (I mean a photo. Not a attachment link) on their friends wall.

Is that possible?

Actually this *might* remove the possibility of asking permissions for `publish_stream` as user will have entire control over what to publish and what not..

Comment: You know you cannot post to someone's wall without permissions right?

Comment: @MihaiIorga yeah!! publish_stream!! but it isn't showing error!!

Comment: The problem is, I don't know JS. I am just using my little intuition & some scripts on web!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm almost sure it's not supported to post to another user's `/photos` connection - 
When you retrieve the post ID you get, are you sure it's not appearing in your own profile / your own activity log?

{edit} there is no dialog which simulates the 'upload a photo to a friend's profile' functionality of facebook.com {/edit}

Comment: Yeah. I didn't find it on my friends profile. (Its just working on my profile)

Comment: That's your answer then, you can't post a photo to another user's photo albums - you can post to their timeline via the `feed` connection though but it'll be a post with a photo attached, not a full sized photo

Comment: Is there any way to perform this without asking respective permissions (publish_stream).. I would like to make a fb.ui event.. I want it to publish as a Photo.

Comment: I changed the question to make it sense... this is what I was exactly looking at. So, could you please rephrase your answer!!

Comment: Hey, I think you are right, apps doesn't have permissions to post photos on friends wall. But unknowingly (when I was actually learning graph api) I used `/friend_id/photos` connection and it worked. I didn't open the app for quite some time.. Now, I am unable to do that! The issue is, I am neither able to perform other Graph Actions on friends too (like posting message for feed) which are accepted. Can you please help me on it? I think you are FB developer !!

Comment: is my app banned or anything.. I just don't know why its happening

Comment: can you please look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237172/can-we-post-photos-on-friends-wall-using-graph-api (**Status: High**. I think its a facebook bug)

Answer (score 0):

@Surya: You need the user's permission to post photos on his wall, and for that you need his permission to access his photos, which is achieved by the "publish_stream" parameter in your request. As far as your question is concerned, posting photos on your friends wall doesn't seem to possible. Even if it is possible it won't post it to your friend's wall unless he/she permits that. There is a way by which you can post the videos/photos but as a link and not as proper photos. Also I had noticed one more thing when I was trying to use photo sharing graph api, that it doesn't publish photos to your account immediately. It seeks the user's permission to be published, else the photos remain in his unpublished albums. You will find that album when you click on "Photos" section of your account. Check out my blog for more details :)

http://bashwithflash.blogspot.in/2012/05/photo-sharing-on-facebook-using-graph.html
http://bashwithflash.blogspot.in/2012/05/album-sharing-on-facebook-using-graph.html

Comment: @TushriaGupta actually I have used Graph API in server side python scripts and took "publish_stream" permissions. lately I found that JS SDK calls are quite better than server side calls as they make page loading better. so, is there any way to sync between these two. I mean, can I take permissions on the server side and do actions in client side JS?

Comment: Let me go through the above article first