# Can we post photos on friends wall using Graph API

Tags: javascript, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is it possible to `upload` photos on friends wall? The documentation never mentioned that! but its happening. **I am able to post to the `/friend_id/photos` connection.**

I am actually running my app on local server using localhost tunneling. So, in August, I made an app where people can post photos on their friends wall (upon their request only). So, As I was pretty new to FB API, I didn't notice that it is not allowed.

I just left the app for few weeks and came back to fix things **and I noticed that I am unable to post photos to the `/friend_id/photos` connection** (Its just not working. I am not getting any errors). Its not even working for other *possible* connections like `/friend_id/feed` Is my app restricted to some graph actions?

**So, I just created a test app and executed the same connection `/friend_id/photos` and **its working.** Don't know why!**

This is not the end of surprise:

1. I successfully posted a photo on my friends wall using my test app
2. When I opened the photo, I could see its from "Surya's Photos" - my photos
3. I don't see that photo in my albums. I just don't know where its actually saved.

[image]

Comment: Isn't there also a response on error? Did you try printing the response?

Comment: I am not getting any error as response! thats the point

Comment: @Tosh so.. what could be the possible reason

Comment: Not possible, your if statement can only go two ways, response or error. Check your Developer console.

Comment: Don't use alert, but console.log(); Add console.log(response) so you can see the value of the response.

Comment: @Tosh Now, I can see a "object" as response and it has many properties in it! but apart from all these things, I see the following error:`Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined 
(anonymous function)` why would I get such one!

Comment: @Tosh please look into my django template http://dpaste.com/795673/

Comment: @phwd please look into my django template http://dpaste.com/795673/

Comment: Well if FB is not defined there's your problem. For some reason the sdk js library is not loaded at the time this part of your code is executed

Comment: @Tosh I fixed that error (I was causing by some other script).. So, Still I am unable to post on friends wall even though I am getting "posted" alert. I check on console, its returning an object and I don't see any such parameter looking like "error"

Comment: One rule, `access_token` should be valid, doesn't really matter how it was created. The question is probably should be **"Can we post photos on friends wall?"**

Comment: @JuicyScripter We can post! I did that from the server side for some time. Thought to do it using JS as it increases performance. I used the same access token for that!

Comment: @JuicyScripter I mentioned couple of links above please look into them. I don't want to post photos as feed with attachment. I want them to be as "Photos" itself

Comment: @Surya, non of the links you provided mentioning posting of `photo` to other `user`/friend wall. First is about posting `photo` to specific `album` (owned by user who own the `access_token`), and second about posting `post` to friend's `feed`.

Comment: @JuicyScripter Please take a look at the above edited question how I did the action on the server side successfully! Hope it clears the air between us

Comment: @Surya, It's not really clear from the screenshot, looks like a regular post with `source` provided. On the other side there is a bunch of unanswered questions on subject and no single working sample around, but lots of statements that this isn't possible ([even one of Facebook developers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12123802/155033) in answer to your own question says this isn't possible).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16377/discussion-between-surya-and-juicy-scripter)

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2:**  This is indeed possible (is it a bug?) the same regular way.

But seems that posting of `photo` to other user's `/photos` connection behave very differently from posting to `/me/photos`. Here are some of the facts about posting to `/FRIEND_ID/photos`:

1. Every `photo` published that way creates separated album named `Posting User's photos` (that's it uploaded photos will never be grouped and there is no way to see all of them in single place).
2. That `photo` will not be visible in albums of either user or friend, but only will be seen/accessible via feed/timeline.
3. And for sure this is only working if you able to post on that friend's feed

So it really behaves just like any other content posted to friend's `feed`.

I would say if you not rely on album functionality and persistance of those photos and only want to "share" photo on friend's wall, go for it (unless it's proven to be bug).

---

**TL;DR;** <strike>No you cannot post `photo` to friend's `/photos` connection.</strike> Well, you can post `photo` to friend's `/photos` connection but it will not behave the same way if posted to your's `/photos`.

According to documentation of [`photos`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos) connection for [`user`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user):

> **Create**
>   You can post photos to a user's Wall on their behalf by issuing an HTTP POST request to PROFILE_ID/photos with the publish_stream permissions and the following parameters.

Also according to documentation of [`photo`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) object:

> `https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/photos` - The photo will be published to an album created for your app. We automatically create an album for your app if it does not already exist. All photos uploaded this way will then be added to this same album.

So generally speaking you trying to upload photo to other user's album but you may only post photos to your profile (or to page if using `access_token` for page).

You may however post to [`feed`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#feed) of other user (for example `post` may or may not have `picture` as attachement, which isn't the same as `photo`).

<strike>**Update:**
Photos may only be uploaded to `/USER_ID/photos` than `USER_ID` is the same as `me` (owner of `access_token`).</strike>

Comment: I have publish_stream permissions. so, why can't I post them.. I have seen couple of tutorials. If this is not the right way, can you please explain it clearly

Comment: @Surya, You using `access_token` which doesn't belong to owner of the photo. I've added more details, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: I really don't understand. As above mentioned, FB Docs says that we can post photos to friend profile.. That's what I am doing here!!

Comment: @Surya, none of the documentation says about friends. And non of examples in links you provided contain posting of photo to friend's feed.

Comment: Hey, this is **surprising**. I just made a test app and made a connection to `/friend_id/photos` and its working!!!

Answer (score 0):

> Is my app restricted to some graph actions?

There’s some places where FB say in the docs or developer blog posts, “If you misuse feature *xy*, your app’s ability to use it may be revoked” (not literally; I’m paraphrasing here, but something like that).

So it’s absolutely possible, that FB revoked the ability to post photos to friend’s walls specially for *your* app, because too many users receiving photos on their walls this way have marked them as “spam”.

(“Revoking a permission” is maybe not the exactly correct wording here; I think it’s more likely the Graph API accepts the requests made from your app in the first place, but then silently filters it out in the back; that would also explain why you not get any errors.)

Comment: I just posted a bug in Facebook.. Hope they respond. Is it possible for them to restore those permissions for me. What is the best way to reach facebook on this issue.

Comment: Why would you post a _bug report_ for this? You app’s behavior being considered “spammy” by users is not a “bug” on the platform, but your own fault.

Comment: Didn't you read the question. **I am able to connect /friend_id/photos** which shouldn't be possible at all. Moreover, I was just testing my app on my friends (I never deployed in to the whole public). No one ever mentioned it as spammy. I personally verified with them.

Comment: _“I am able to connect /friend_id/photos which shouldn't be possible at all.”_ – says who, exactly? I have not read definitive proof here, that the docs actually say so anywhere; just people “assuming” it was not possible. To post a photo to a user’s wall (not a specific album), you only need publish_stream permission. And if a user is allowed to post other kinds of posts to a friends wall, then I don’t see why posting a photo should not be possible as well.

Comment: @Surya, can you provide us with a link to bug posting so we can also follow up the issue?

Comment: @JuicyScripter Actually, what CBroe said is right. It is absolutely possible to post photo on friends wall. And... my issue has been close by their engineers.